# Show or hide component according to the current path in React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I want to show or hide `NewsLetter` according to the current path. For example I want it hidden for `login` and `register` pages, i.e., (path login & register). I have tried using `useLocation` but it cannot be used outside of the router.

I hope to get a good solution so that I can also render navbar and footer in similar conditions too. Here is my current code inside `App.js`:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Wrapper>
    <Announcement />
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route index path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
      <Route path="/products" element={<ProductList />}></Route>
      <Route path="/products/:category" element={<ProductList category="true" />}></Route>
      <Route path="/product/:id" element={<Product />}></Route>
      <Route path="/register" element={isAuthenticated ? <Navigate replace to="/" /> : <Register />}></Route>
      <Route path="/login" element={isAuthenticated ? <Navigate replace to="/" /> : <Login />}></Route>
      <Route path="/account" element={isAuthenticated ? <Navigate replace to="/" /> : <Account />}></Route>
      <Route path="/forgot-password" element={isAuthenticated ? <Navigate replace to="/" /> : <ForgotPassword />}></Route>
      <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />}></Route>
      <Route path="/wishlist" element={<Wishlist />}></Route>
      <Route path="/orders/tracking" element={<Tracking />}></Route>
      <Route path="/orders/checkout" element={<Checkout />}></Route>
    </Routes>
    <Newsletter />
  </Wrapper>
  <Footer />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 2):

## First solution

You could simply leave `Newsletter` component where it's inside `BrowserRouter` and change its content as below. Using `useLocation` either it renders its content or return an empty JSX depending on the path.

```js
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const Newsletter = () => {
  // ...
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  // ...
  if (pathname === "/login" || pathname === "/register") {
    return <></>;
  }
  // render actual content
  return <div></div>;
};
export default Newsletter;
```

## Second one

Another way is to control everything in one place by creating a `Layout.js` commponent, like so:

```js
import { Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Layout = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  return (
    <>
      <Announcement />
      <Navbar />
      <Outlet />
      {pathname !== "/login" && pathname !== "/register" && <Newsletter />}
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Then change your routes set up as below. Notice the `Layout` component. Make sure to import it:

```js
// ⚠️  Other imports
import Layout from "./components/Layout"; // ⚠️ Verify it's the correct path

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Wrapper>
          <Routes>
            <Route element={<Layout />}>
              <Route index path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
              <Route path="/products" element={<ProductList />}></Route>
              {/* Other routes... */}
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Wrapper>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

You can have as many layouts as you want (`MainLayout`, `AuthLayout`, `Layout`...). The setup is the same, an `Outlet` and a `Route` that has your `Layout` as `element` and wraps the pages for that `Layout`.

Comment: This works! Meaning I will have to write the same code for checking the condition again inside the other components like the Navbar and Footer, that I would want to render according to the same rule?

Comment: Yeah that's it, each component knows where it should render.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have decided to stick with this solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try with nested route by using Outlet in Newsletter component

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Wrapper>
   <Announcement />
   <Navbar />
   <Routes >
       <Route exact path="/" element={<Newsletter />} >
           <Route index element={<Home />}></Route>
           <Route path="products" element={<ProductList />}></Route>
           <Route path="products/:category" element={<ProductList category="true" />}></Route>
           <Route path="product/:id" element={<Product />}></Route>
           <Route path="register" element={isAuthenticated ? <Navigate replace to="/" /> : <Register />}></Route>
           <Route path="login" element={isAuthenticated ? <Navigate replace to="/" /> : <Login />}></Route>
           <Route path="account" element={isAuthenticated ? <Navigate replace to="/" /> : <Account />}></Route>
           <Route path="forgot-password" element={isAuthenticated ? <Navigate replace to="/" /> : <ForgotPassword />}></Route>
           <Route path="cart" element={<Cart />}></Route>
           <Route path="wishlist" element={<Wishlist />}></Route>
           <Route path="orders/tracking" element={<Tracking />}></Route>
           <Route path="orders/checkout" element={<Checkout />}></Route>
       </Route>
   </Routes>
 </Wrapper>
 <Footer />
</BrowserRouter>
```

and in Newsletter component

```
const Newsletter = () => {
    ... your conditions 

    return (
        <Outlet /> 
        ... newsletter content
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you are looking for this :

```
window.location.pathname
```

Comment: I have tried using window.location.pathname but I is not dynamic in that I can't change when the path gets updated

Comment: don't store it in a different variable just use it directly it will get updated each time your route changes.

Comment: I have tried your solution, working but not dynamic in that you have to reload the page to effect the changes

Comment: @AbhishekMittal please provide a solution based on what OP questions. Your solution is just to get the current pathname and the problem is the window.location.pathname doesn't change when the route is changed.